# Return Enum of null dynamically using the Type

Tags: c#, enums, .net-core-3.0

In a serializer I have

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var enumText = reader.Value.ToString();
        var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
        var defaultValue = GetDefault(objectType);
        //TODO: If empty or invalid, return null
        if (enumText == string.Empty)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        ...
    }
```

objectType is ``` System.Nullable``1[[SomeEnum]] ``` where SomeEnum is a normal enum

What should the `GetDefault` be to return an instance of `System.Nullable[SomeEnum]` of value `null`?

I tried 
`Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);` which returns `null` instead of `(SomeEnum?)null`

I also tried

```
    public object GetDefault(Type t)
    {
        return GetType().GetMethod("GetDefaultGeneric").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public T GetDefaultGeneric<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
```

Which also returns null

Is it possible to return `(SomeEnum?)null` but from a Type object?

I test this with a unit test like this:

```
        var converter = new CustomStringEnumConverter();

        var result = converter.ReadJson(_readerMock.Object, nullableEnumType, "bad value", new JsonSerializer());
        result.Should().BeOfType(GetUnderlyingType(nullableEnumType));
        result.Should().Be(GetValue(nullableEnumType, null));
```

Test passes if I return `(SomeEnum?) null` but fails if result is `null`

Comment: Have you tried to use [`GetValueOfDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8) method for that? If the `HasValue` property is `false`, the method returns the `default` value of the underlying type.

Comment: where is this method? it's not on the objectType

Comment: You somehow need to activate the instance to call this method and if I could do that, I wouldn't be having an issue to begin with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `null` from the `ReadJson` method should be all you need to do. `Nullable<T>` is a value type (even though you can test for and assign `null` to it). When it gets boxed into a referenced type (`object` for example), then it does one of two things:

1. If the value represented by `Nullable<T>` is NOT `null`, then the `Value` is boxed just like any other value type would be.
2. If `Nullable<T>` is reprsenting a `null` value, then the result is actually `null`.

The reverse happens when you unbox (going from a reference type to `Nullable<T>`); if the reference type is `null`, then a new instance of `Nullable<T>` is created and is set such that it does not have a value, but if the reference type does hold a value, then a new `Nullable<T>` instance is created and the value within the reference type is set to be the current value of the `Nullable<T>`.

The reason calling `GetValueOrDefault` doesn't work is because, for `Nullable<T>` the return type of that method is `T`, which must be a value type, so it cannot be `null`.

Comment: Wrong, if I return null then the unit test fails because:

result.Should().BeOfType(enumType); blows up because result is null instead of (Enum?) null

Comment: Test would pass if I return (Enum?) null ;

Comment: I think the issue is the unit test. I don't know exactly how the assertion library you are using has implemented the type test.

Comment: the unit tests simply serializes the enum:
var result = converter.ReadJson(_readerMock.Object, nullableEnumType, value, new JsonSerializer());

Comment: Right. Ignore the assertion library for now, and see if you can typecast the result of `ReadJson` to the nullable enum. I expect that to work. I didn't put this in my answer because I'm not 100%, but I don't believe `null` has a type, it just means "nothing". You can assign `null` to variables that have been declared as a specific type, but that doesn't mean it's a "string `null`" or whatever, it's just a declared variable that currently holds nothing.

Comment: But the objectType is not a nullable. It's a nullable of type EnumX so I don't see why activating that returns null instead of EnumX?

Comment: The issue isn't really with the unit test. When I debug I can find no way to create an EnumX? = null instance.

Comment: Your return type is `object`. When you box a `Nullable<T>`, it will become a boxed `T` or a (typeless) null reference. What you want is not possible. If your unit test assumes it must work, I would like to see the writer of said test write *any* method that would work with that test. You cannot. It's not how the language works.

Comment: Add it as an answer that what I want is not possible and I'll accept it, provided someone doesn't come up with a way to actually do it